# Installing IRAF problem

Tags: installation, bash

I've installed iraf v216 on my desktop computer without any difficulties but installing it on laptop(HP pavilion g6) is giving me a lots of trouble.
I can't solve this particular problem, and I don't know what to do, I'm new to linux, but I can follow your steps easily. ;)
Here is the problem:
Iraf installation passed, x11IRAF too, ds9 also passed but when I try to run it it says `bash: /usr/local/bin/xgterm: No such file or directory`
and xgterm is located in "/usr/local/bin/".

I have no idea what to do from here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem yesterday while trying to install IRAF 2.14 and x11IRAF 1.3.1 on Xubuntu 12.10.  From [this helpful post](http://iraf.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=139657), I realized that the issue was that xgterm needs the following 32bit libraries that were not by default installed on my system:

libx11-dev

ia32-libs

These libraries are in the Ubuntu repositories, so an apt-get should do the trick.